# Handle HTTP state in model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How to handle different XHR states in backbone model after fetch?

I need to track all states - both success and error states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch (and other Backbone.sync methods) will return an xhr value, which you can store in a variable:

```
var xhr = myModel.fetch();

xhr.fail(...);
```

Comment: Yes it works. And second argument in fail callback is XHR, from where I can get state by XHR.status